# Existing sales/ordering engine that can be integrated to custom .NET app?

Tags: .net, catalog, integrate, product

There's this custom who wants software to generate quotes from a product catalog, print invoices, nothing too original here.
But they also want a bunch of custom features and a custom presentation, so buy off-the-shelf won't do.

Do you know any good product that we could integrate in the custom dev instead of reinventing the wheel for the catalog/order/invoice management part of the app ?

This is a .NET project in a Microsoft environment.

Any suggestions / reviews are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There's a load of ASP.NET starter kits on the Microsoft site [here](http://www.asp.net/community/projects/)

I don't know whether it's what you need, but there's e-commerce, shop sites, etc, and it seems you can alter the code and use it as you see fit (read the license first!)